# Spring custom date parsing using a custom PropertyEditor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form which sends date fields in a specific format(dd-MMMM-yy),i am trying to setup my spring application so it can automatically parse dates into a java.util.Date object.

One way i have approached this is to first create a custom PropertyEditorSupport class which will deal with the parsing my dates the are incoming from/outgoing to the form

```
public class DateTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String value) {
        try {
            setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy").parse(value));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            setValue(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        String stringDate = "";
        try {
            stringDate= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yy").format((Date)getValue());  
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //
        } 
        return stringDate
    }
}
```

Then create a custom PropertyEditorRegistrar to register the above PropertyEditorSupport to handle Dates

```
public class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateTimeEditor());
    }
}
```

Create the bean in the spring context

```
<bean id="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.test.CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I can see the method registerCustomEditors of the CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar class being invoked several times but the methods(setAsText or getAsText) in the DateTimeEditor never get invoked.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your editor to spring binding in Controller class...

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateTimeEditor());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Make sense that the property editor would need to be registered with the controllers webdatabinder for the editor to be used for requests to my controllers.